# How do I edit a value in an OMElement

Tags: java, debugging, element

I'm trying to replace a value in the `Value` tag in an `OMElement`.

My code is only adding to it (the 564.12 value below it).

```
<b:UI022002D>
  <b:Description>Box 2a (Taxable Amount)</b:Description>
  <b:UIRef>UI022002D</b:UIRef>
  <b:Value>564.1200</b:Value>
  564.12
</b:UI022002D>
```

Code:

```
ArrayList
<OMElement> 
  aElem=getChildrenByPath(oForm, xpathNonUniueTag); 
  for(int i=0;i <aElem.size();i++) { 
    OMElement elem=aElem.get(i); 
    if (xpathNonUniueTag=="*/AmountFields/FormAmountField") { 
      if (sValue.length()> 2){ 
        elem.setText(getChildText(elem, "Value").substring(0, sValue.length() - 2));
      } 
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer:

```
private void mapNonUniqueNodes(OMElement oForm, String sFormID, String xpathNonUniueTag, String xpathChildNodeWithUniqueTag, 
                               String sDescTag)
{


        ArrayList<OMElement> aElem=getChildrenByPath(oForm, xpathNonUniueTag);
    for(int i=0;i<aElem.size();i++)
    {
        OMElement elem=aElem.get(i);
        String newTagName=getChildText(elem, xpathChildNodeWithUniqueTag);

        newTagName=newTagName.replace("-", "");
        String sDescTagValue=getChildText(elem, sDescTag); 



        if (xpathNonUniueTag == "*/AmountFields/FormAmountField") {


            ArrayList<OMElement> aElem2=getChildrenByPath(elem, "*/Value");
            log.info("aElem2  " + aElem2);
            for(int e=0;e<aElem2.size();e++)
            {
                OMElement elem2=aElem2.get(e);

                String sValue = elem2.getText();
                if (sValue.length() > 2){
                    sValue = sValue.substring(0, sValue.length() - 2);

                elem2.setText(sValue);
                log.info("elem2 " + elem2);
                log.info("elem2 text " + elem2.getText());
                }
            }

        }
        }
```